# ASP.NET MVC Cannot add users to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

EDIT: I recognised that I was passing the value Name as id in the controller when it should be ID so I have created a ID field in the userAdd class.

I have set up an ASP.NET MVC small application on Visual Studio 2019 just so I can get on with the basics of its architecture.

What my **intention** is:

I am trying to create a user via an HTML form that adds the user to the database table User. The user will then be displayed when it returns to the page with a list of users after the user has been created. I am passing 2 values from the registration form provided (Name and Email).

What is happening is that when I enter the user details on the form and click submit, nothing happens once the submit button is clicked. No compiler errors that I can see. If I return to the list of users, there has not been a new user created.

When I am building the view, I have set the template to create and selected the correct model class and no context class.

My user DAO and IDAO are;
DAO;

```
public void AddUser(User user, TheContext context)
{
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

IDAO;

```
void AddUser(User user, TheContext context);
```

My user service layer code is:

Service:

```
public void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
{
    User newUser = new User()
    {
        Name = userAdd.Name,
        Email = userAdd.Email
    };

    using (var context = new TheContext())
    {
        userDAO.AddUser(newUser, context);
    }
}
```

IService:

```
 void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd);
```

Controller for adding users:

```
public class AddUserController : Controller
{
    IUserService userService;

    // POST: AddUser/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            userService.AddUser(userAdd);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The class that stores the values from the user creation form:

```
public class UserAdd
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is the database table shown in T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [ID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]  NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

The HTML for adding users:

```
@model Assignment.Services.Models.UserAdd

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddUser";
}

<h2>AddUser</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>UserAdd</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go Back", "GetUsers", "User")
</div>
```

Can someone please explain where I may have gone wrong and what I could do to rectify it? I will continue to look at it myself.

Comment: if you transfer the `context` in the `AddUser DAO` and just pass the `User user`? Will it save?

Comment: Could you show your html page with your submitt button pls?

Comment: @Sergey Done that for you

Answer (score 0):

These two links will probably help.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Maybe it would help to create a sql server database and then connect to Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Change your Htm beginform to this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
```

Change your controller name to UsersController and move all your user actions in one place You don't neee a special controller for each action.

And add route attribute to your action

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    IUserService userService;
public  UsersController()
{
userService=new UserService();
 }
    [Route("~/Users/AddUser")]
   public ActionResult AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
  
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            userService.AddUser(userAdd);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this and it has not worked, still the same scenario where it will not commit any changes after the submit button is clicked

Comment: Pls publish  the whole code of your Users controller

Comment: Change your controller name to UsersController .

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it fixed but another issue has arisen, i'll have to post another question